# Memory leak, Spring for Android

Tags: java, android, spring, memory-leaks

I have a potential memory leak at my code and I'm trying to find a solution. I'm using the Spring for Android framework. And more specific the

```
  RestTemplate.exchange();
```

In order to make an on the fly binding. However, when i make a memory analysis I get the following:

1.628 instances of "com.products.Product", loaded by "dalvik.system.PathClassLoader @ 0x43692b80" occupy 1.363.064 (22,20%) bytes. These instances are referenced from one instance of "java.lang.Object[]", loaded by "". The dominator tree is the following:

> class com.products.ProductList @ 0x436d7ea8 System Class|        1.628 |            8 |           130.240 |             8
>
> > > > mFilteredProducts java.util.ArrayList @ 0x43a4eab0|        1.628 |           24 |           130.240 |         6.552
> > > >
> > > > > > > array java.lang.Object[1628] @ 0x43bdc888|        1.628 |        6.528 |           130.240 |         6.528
> > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > [274] com.products.Product @ 0x4398b038|            1 |           80 |                80 |           760
> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > [1175] com.products.Product @ 0x43b26868|            1 |           80 |                80 |           808
> > > > > > > > > >
> > > > > > > > > > ........

The above one is the dominator tree. However I was wondering if there is a safe way to activate the garbage collector. Is the

```
  System.gc();
```

Safe? However,is there a way to stop taking this memory leak?
 The class com.products.Product is just a simple POJO which will bind the JSON fields to the corresponding attributes. Generally the POJO that is used to bind the JSON is as following:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) //must be there all times most likely
public class MyPojo {

@JsonProperty("Products")
private ArrayList<Product> products;

public ArrayList<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(ArrayList<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}
}
```

com.products.Product:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) //must be there all times most likely
public class Products {

 @JsonProperty
 private String prodnum;
 @JsonProperty
 private String brand;
 @JsonProperty
 private String name;

       //get/set
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `System.gc()` is safe. But it doesn't necessarily trigger the actual garbage collection. Calling this method only *suggests* JVM to make all the efforts to perform garbage collection. There is no way in Java to force it though.

Regarding the memory leak. Look at the `ProductList`, why is it holding all those objects. If ProductList is still referenced from anywhere in your application all those products will not be released.

Answer (score 0):

System.gc() is safe as @wajda already said

Today I had similar problem with desktop application and the problem was that I wasn't closing PreparedStatement and ResultSet objects after usage. After about 600 queries I filled up 256mb of allocated space. After using JVisualVM (you should have it in your JDK) and analyzing what is piling up, I saw char arrays taking 80% of space and they were all empty.

Try and close all JSON objects after each usage and see if it helps.

Cheers